# Restrict employees access to suppliers in OpenERP 7

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7

Can anyone help me to restrict employees from accessing the suppliers and also restrict them from the notes of customers in OpenERP 7.

I am trying to setup a Contact Centre platform using OpenERP 7, where i can have Service Requests.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can't restrict all access to the partners table (contains suppliers and customers) as the system will probably not work at all.  As of OpenERP 7, res.partners also contains contacts and each user has a contact so if you block all access you will probably break a lot of things (YMMV).  You may be able to get away with allowing read access only.

The easiest would be to alter the views of customers and suppliers to add a security group that most users don't belong to so they can't see the view at all.

You will have to track down the form views but you can do this pretty easily through:

Settings -> Technical -> User Interface -> Views and search for the object res.partner.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a rule on the Partner object for your employee group - [('customer','=',True)] - that way only customers are shown, i.e. only those suppliers will be shown who are also customers. You could then also take away the Suppliers menu for the cosmetics.